# How to Schedule a task with command prompt in windows 7?

Tags: windows, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule a task with cmd prompt.The command that I am running is:

```
C:\Windows\system32\schtasks.exe /CREATE /SC ONLOGON /TN "mytask" /TR "C:\samp.txt" /RU "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" /RP /F
```

The task is showing in task manager with username as SYSTEM ,and its status is Running with code 0x41301.But it(samp.txt) is not showing in desktop.

The same command if I am replacing the "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" with currently logged on user then it(samp.txt) is showing on desktop.

How can I make the task to display on desktop with /RU "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to add `/IT` ?
This is the only option which may allow you to display something on the active session using scheduled tasks. However, I am not sure that Windows will allow to interact with the desktop of another user.

**Edit :** You may use `/RU BUILTIN\Users /IT`, so any user will be able to run it interactively. What is you constraint on /RU system ?

If your goal is to display the samp.txt file content when a user logs on, another solution is to put the samp.txt in the startup folder of the "all users" start menu : `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Comment: Yes, I tried with /IT option but it is not working.Placing the file in Startup folder will run that file at logon time only.I need to schedule the task at different time..

Comment: @123r789: then update your sample command, which is confusing. Am not sure if there is a solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

could you try with psexec ?
your command will be something like :

```
PSEXEC -i -s -d -w c:\ notepad.exe samp.txt
```

Comment: It is giving error like PSEXEC is not recognized as internal or external command.

Comment: psexec is part of the [pstools suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx), you have to download and copy it to your path first

Comment: Here my actual requirement is shedule a task in client system with my installer.So without using pstools suite I need to schedule the task.